# How to create campfire which will burn overnight?

Tags: camping, fire

I watched a documentary "Man vs Wild" which showed the TV presenter Bear Grylls collecting wood and starting a fire. He somehow always manages to keep his campfire burning until dawn. How does one know how much wood to collect such that it is adequate to last throughout the night? Is there a certain method of arranging the wood pile consisting of broken branches and twigs to maximize the period of combustion?

Comment: I think the primary method employed is the "TV producers and staff keep it going while the camera isn't running" method.

Comment: Bear in mind that leaving a campfire burning unattended overnight increases the risks of starting a wildfire (a major problem in some parts of the US), and may be banned wherever you're camping.

Comment: When building a campfire, if you set the logs further apart they get more air and burn faster. If you set the logs closer together, they get less air and burn slower.

Comment: A better ethic would be not to burn so much wood. Leave No Trace is a really good philosophy.

Comment: @BenCrowell you might consider a human corpse a trace as well... Of course you are right - you should not do that for fun. However, its good to know how to do it if you ever need it (for survival, not to impress your friends)

Comment: Take EVERYTHING you see on Man vs Wild with a grain of salt. Bear doesn't actually do the survival. He stages pieces of it for TV. I have seen bad advice given by him, and he was proved a fraud a few years back, at least for the show. Personally, I like Survivorman, because it's real. No crew, no fakery. Success, or failure, he shows it all.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to create a campfire that burns all night `unattended`, but certainly embers and coals will continue to be hot through most of the night. In my experience, embers and coals cool down in the early morning hours (3a - 4am). If you want to keep the fire itself going you need to keep adding/rearranging/stoking the wood every hour or so.

Comment: You have to tend the fire throughout the night to keep it burning. If you cat-nap outdoors like I do, just toss another log on the fire every time you wake up to roll over. Of course fires while you're sleeping are only necessary if you have insufficient bedding to keep warm, and I don't mean comfortably warm, I mean stay-alive warm.

Comment: @TomCollins - Man vs Wild and Survivor Man are two *completely* different shows. Where Survivor Man is teaching you how to avoid exposure and danger, Bear is diving *head first* into danger to show you how to get out of it. You'll never see Survivor man doing press-ups in his birthday suit after swimming under ice in the Arctic. Bear Grylls has serious thrill issues, and it makes for a much more entertaining show. I forgive him of any shortcuts he may take on set in exchange for such quality adventure in my living room. Not doing it off camera doesn't mean he doesn't have the skills.

Comment: @ShemSeger, if he would advertise his show as "for entertainment purposes only", I'd be willing to give him a break. But when he says "I'm an expert, do what I say", when some of what he does is questionable, and other things are just wrong, then I'm going to call BS on his show. It's very irresponsible, as some people believe whatever he says.

Comment: @TomCollins - When is the last time you watched a primetime show that was for education purposes only? I question many of the things Survivor Man does too. He does a lot of episodes in my province, I've noticed a couple of times where he plays on the audiences ignorance when he's in the woods in BC.

Comment: I once had a not-so-bright friend and I had to spend a full hour explaining to him how Bear wasn't out there alone in the woods. My friend was convinced that it was just Bear, a camera and a tripod. Knowing a little bit about TV production, I had to explain to him how ***at minimum*** there were three other people with him. Took me a full hour to make my friend realize that Bear is not superman out alone in the woods . . . My friend has a college degree too and a good job - some people are just stupid.

Comment: I remember reading Swallows and Amazons where Susan uses a charcoal burners' technique to keep her going campfire overnight. She uses pieces of turf to cover the fire and dampens them. Would this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly how long wood you've gathered will last you, unless as an expert you can gauge an accurate estimate due to the type of wood, weather conditions and other contributing factors (theoretically possible, but above my ability level.)

However, there are different ways of constructing a fire, and one in particular is designed to burn for long periods, such as overnight, without requiring any maintenance or fiddling about through the night (if done correctly.)

This is known as a **pyramid fire**:

[image: Diagram of pyramid fire]

You place two logs parallel on the ground to start with, then place a row of smaller logs perpendicular and on top of the original two, then another row perpendicular and on top of that row, and so on. You then light the fire at the top, and instinctively quite bizarrely the fire will then burn downwards (as each level becomes hot enough to ignite the layer below it.)

Image taken from [here](http://wildernessarena.com/food-water-shelter/firecraft/building-a-fire).

Comment: The trick to a long lasting fire is to limit the oxygen to it. Your pyramid stack would do the opposite. You'd get a really roaring fire for a relatively short time for the amount of wood used. Also I suspect Bear regularly attends to the fire during the night. There is a lot of stuff they don't show you. I like Survivorman better. Les does things ordinary people can do (Bear is a former special forces guy), and it's less staged.

Comment: Les Stroud is the man. :)  Definitely prefer him over Man v. Wild, simply because it's real - he doesn't have a safety camp right around the corner.  It's just him, with one exception where the lawyers stepped in.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I have tried something similar to a pyramid fire once, somewhat by accident (though admittedly only once) whilst trying to construct a roaring fire - and it burnt pretty slowly and steadily, contrary to what I expected. It wasn't windy and was rather cold at the time, so admittedly this may not be an accurate representation. However, when looking around online I found the above page which seemed to suggest the same thing, so assumed that was therefore a reliable way of achieving it. I may well of course be wrong, you no doubt have more experience at these things than I.

Comment: @DonB: I don't remember a episode where lawyers got envolved. Could you elaborate? Even though Les has to manage the cameras all by himself, I find the camera work of Man vs Wild more annoying. The guy pans and zooms way too much while you're trying to watch. It seems to have gotten worse lately so I stopped watching. Dual Survival also seems quite staged at times, although it can be fun to watch the two together. Cody knows what he's doing, but is a preachy prick a lot, and the new guy Joe sometimes does dumb stuff. The previous guy Dave was better.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Can't remember if this was shared on-screen or off-screen, but there was an episode of Survivorman where the lawyers decided the risk was just too great, and insisted that there be a camp nearby.  It would have been an older episode, since I don't have cable and only watch the show on Netflix.

Comment: @DonBranson: I think there was one where he went to Labrador, and the episode was cut short because the producers sent a helicopter crew to pick him up because there was some imminent storm or something, perhaps that's what you're thinking?

Comment: @whatsisname No.  I think it was the one where he used a plane as a shelter in the Arctic, eating only rabbits.

Comment: Thanks for the informative link. I think this is a plausible solution if the fire is lit on top. The rate of combustion may somewhat be controlled since the air can still be cool below the flames. This is provided that the spacing between the logs is small enough to prevent burning material from falling to the bottom and lighting up the whole pile.

Comment: @OlinLathrop This method does work! I know it seems counter intuitive and looks identical to the fire used to create lots of embers quickly for cooking on (Log Cabin fire). The difference is, this fire is burned from the top down (heat rises) and the other (faster) burning, burns from the bottom up.

Comment: Hard wood (maple, oak, walnut, etc.) will burn longer than soft wood (pine, etc.).

Comment: It's not clear ***why*** you want a fire to burn all night. Do you need heat from the fire or are you just looking to keep a fire alive so that it will still be alive in the morning. The answer really depends on what you need. Hopefully you need the latter, which requires a lot less fuel and heat generation (and is correspondingly safer and less wasteful).

Answer (score 23):

To get a long lasting fire, you have to limit the cumbustion somehow.  Think embers as apposed to much flame.

Wood stoves are specifically engineered to allow you to control the rate of combustion.  This is done by controlling the air intake to the fire, which limits oxygen, which limits the combustion rate.  A wood stove can be built nicely sealed, so the biggest problem is providing enough oxygen to keep the fire going.

In the wild, this is much more difficult as you don't have a nicely sealed fire box with a single air intake you can control.  The best you can do usually is to emulate a fire box with rocks and stuff up some of the openings with mud and the like.  Still, there will be more oxygen than necessary to just keep the fire alive.  There is little alternative to keeping a supply of wood ready and feeding the fire periodically if you really want to sustain a fire.

However, consider whether a sustained fire is really necessary.  You can build something with at least somewhat limited air intake, give it a supply of relatively large pieces of wood, and surround it with lots of rocks.  Even if the fire goes out, the rocks will stay warm for quite a while.  A better strategy is to not require a fire all night long, especially if you are in a place and conditions where the fire could escape if you don't watch it.

Comment: +1, esp for the comment about fire escaping.  In many camping environments, an unattended campfire is banned by park policies because the risk of causing a forest fire.  In some dry areas (esp. the American West) the risk of wildfires is so great that campfires may be banned entirely.

Answer (score 17):

Additional to the other tips and warnings I would like to mention one special tecnique I found in the book "Outdoor Praxis" by Rainer Höh.

Basically it consists of some kind of reflector fire, but the reflector will feed the fire instead. You would stick two or more thick, maybe even green, branches in the soil to support the reflector. Make sure to incline them away from the fire - while this makes the reflector less effective it allows self-feeding. Now pile your firewood up reclining onto the support sticks. Make/move your fire close to the reflector so the one at the bottom starts to burn. While it is burned up, the pile of wood will slip down, allowing the next branch to burn.
This works probably best with wood 5-10cm in diameter. Smaller ones will burn to fast, thicker ones wouldn´t start burning easy enough.

Please note that this needs some practice and doesn´t garantuee that the fire will burn overnight. Still, its better than nothing. If you want to use it for staying warm its perfect, because you can stretch it and it has at least a little reflector.

Illustration (not quite what I am suggesting, since this reflector here isn´t meant to burn and the support sticks would be way to thin, but its similar):[image: reflector fire]

Image taken from [www.survivalistssite.com](http://www.survivalistssite.com/~canuck/page19.html)

---

[image]

Comment: That's cool. Now I want to try it out...

Comment: I added a photo of another way of doing this.

Answer (score 5):

In one of the series of Survivorman the Les Stroud has put into fire the whole fallen pine. 
A very thick trunk will burn for a long time. Generally, the thicker the wood the longer it will burn. A thin branch will last a few hours, the fire will not be big, but it will nevertheless give heat.

Unfortunately I never recorded it, but as far as I remember a very thick branch was burning for a few hours. When it is cold, you wan't sleep the whole night, you would wake up often and you can adjust the campfire then. It's the way Bear Grylls probably manages that, if not helped by the camera crew ;) He almost always make shots in dark saying how cold it is and how bad he sleeps :)

Answer (score 5):

I put a heavy pine log in the wood stove 24 hours ago.  It is still giving off heat and I expect it will burn for another 4-6 hours.  I started the fire by exposing the large log on one side to several pieces of burning tinder.  After the tinder burned out and all flames were gone,  there was red hot embers on one side of the log.  The red hot embers slowly worked from one end of the log to the other, like a slow burning fuse.  The downside is the heat is relatively low level - I estimate the heat output to be 3000-5000 btu/hr.  I was easily able to heat a big pot of stew and a couple kettles of water by placing them near the burning embers.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from getting a few good logs going before bed, I have used a bit of a cheat when taking the scouts camping. I cover the embers (a good bed) with foil. If in abundance you could try using green leaves to act as a reflector though I never tried this. Like [@whatsisname](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/3631/2653) said earlier tv cheat having the fire with flame in the morning. I've only ever had embers, but you can get a fire going very quickly with embers..Bear Grylls task I ask ya

Comment: One caution, foil will burn.  I've gotten many a fire hot enough to burn off aluminum foil.  However as long as it's not too hot, this should work.

Answer (score 5):

Banking a fire outdoors can done, but...it really depends on the area. With the droughts out west, a Leave No Trace fire from a Nimbelwall collapsible stove or a portable gas or alcohol stove is best. To bank a fire really just means to bed down all the pieces of wood sticking up and possibly cover the fire with ashes.

Blocking the prevailing wind with a wind break (big rock, tin, etc) will also slow the burn. If you have built a big enough fire to cook on and have gathered around it for a bit in the evening, there should be enough coals left in the morning to just gently blow the ashes off and add some tinder. My son built one fire at Ottari in VA (smokey mountains) and just stoked it every morning for a week. For Scout outings and in parks this is NOT recommended. Best done in a stove.

Answer (score 2):

#### Finnish Gap Fire

Another option, besides the great answers already posted, is a Finnish gap fire, or Rakovalkea gap fire:

[image: The finished project]

You'll need a hand axe to carve notches into the logs to make them stable (kind of like a partial log cabin wall). Here's the directions from the site: [How To... Build a Finnish Rakovalkea Gap Fire](http://www.bushcraftdays.com/how-to-build-a-finnish-rakovalkea-gap-fire/)

> The component parts are two logs and various green sticks for supports and wedges. I flattened one of the logs in preparation for cutting out a groove in which to start the fire, keeping all the chippings for getting the fire going later. The log was not wet, exactly, but it was slightly damp owing to the heavy rain we have had recently. I could have left this experiment for the summer but thought that if I could get a damp log going then that would be a more realistic test for the UK environment. This type of fire is normally used in dry arctic environments where dead standing pines are abundant.
>
> [image: Create a flat surface on one log]
>
> Once the log was flattened I carved out the channel. This is the dangerous bit, so cut the channel out with small cuts and with the log on the ground or well off to your side. I left flattened areas off to the sides but on reflection I think I should have made the channel the full length to maximize airflow.
>
> [image: Axe out a channel]
>
> On the underside of the log with the channel I axed out two grooves for the support poles.
>
> [image: Under the log with the channel axe out a groove at each end]
>
> The support poles help to stop the log from rolling off to one side. I think if they were big enough they must help when the log is resting on snow to keep it secure.
>
> [image: Bottom log set up]
>
> On the log that I was going to place on top I just flattened one side of it so it would rest securely on top of the bottom log. Again, on reflection, as the log was damp I should have made multiple cuts in this area with my axe to increase the surface area of the log and let the flames catch hold better. I came across this method when researching the Raappanan tuli candle.
>
> [image: Flatten out along a section of the top log]
>
> I carved two wedges that were to be used to vary the gap height between the two logs. These also proved useful as tongs later.
>
> [image: Green wood wedges for adjusting height]
>
> On one of the poles of green wood I carved a point and dug it into the ground beside the set up as support. I made this extra long as I was setting this up on soft earth (on the potato bed my wife had just dug over, in fact, but as it’s not been planted yet no potatoes were harmed in the making of this fire, and as I keep telling her ash is good for the soil).
>
> [image: One sharpened pole for support]
>
> I slimmed down the end of another green stick and hammered a nail into it. One end of the stick is dug into the ground and nailed into the top log (diagonally opposite to the vertically upright green pole)
>
> [image: Nail pole support]
>
> This is the basic set up without any tinders in the middle. All in all (not including foraging the wood) this set up took me about 15 minutes to do. I have read that with the much larger set ups (full body length) someone with good axe skills can set one up in an hour or so.
>
> [image: Basic set up without tinder]
>
> To get the fire going I used a mixture of waxed wood shavings, cotton wool balls smeared in Vaseline, and a lot of dry larch twigs. I did try and find some pine or spruce resin but to no avail. Resin is traditionally used along with pine fat wood.
>
> [image: Filled with tinders]
>
> I lit the whole thing with just a couple of matches and in a few seconds the whole set up was alight.
>
> [image]

All images and quoted text from [How To... Build a Finnish Rakovalkea Gap Fire](http://www.bushcraftdays.com/how-to-build-a-finnish-rakovalkea-gap-fire/).

Comment: Is this something that would burn all night?

Comment: @NateW yes, that's one of the main purposes of this method. That, and evenly heating a lean-to.

Comment: Neat, i just hadn't seen this type of fire before. Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

This [HowWhyWhere article](http://www.howwhywhere.com/Keep-a-Fire-Burning/) has some advice on how to tend a campfire:

> If the fire seems to die out, use a long stick or a fire poker to move the logs and woods around. You should also blow on them, to provide a burst of oxygen. Keep working on the fire until it seems to be stable again, if you neglect it, it will go out.
>
> - A good sign is red, hot charcoal. These are so much hotter than the
>     original wood was, and they will get hotter and hotter as you
>     accumulate them with the fire poker/stick.
> - If all the wood has become charcoal, and if you still want the fire
>     to keep going, make the charcoal glow red by poking and blowing at
>     them, then put on some more tinder, kindling and firewood.

Comment: Yes, this would be the way to rekindle a fire. But how to make it burn all night without needing to do this?

Answer (score 0):

#### Swedish Fire Log

Yet another option is what is known as a Swedish torch or Canadian candle (especially if you have a chain saw available). This type of fire is much more useful as a camp stove as opposed to a heat source. It burns slowly, releasing most of its heat upward (toward the object being cooked). Here's the directions from the site: [How to Make a Swedish Fire Log](https://www.freshoffthegrid.com/swedish-fire-log/).

> [image: Cooking with a Swedish fire log]
>
> A Swedish Fire Log – also referred to as a Swedish Torch or Canadian Candle – is a highly efficient campfire for cooking. First developed by the Swedish army during the Thirty Years War, this type of campfire requires just a single log and can be made even when the ground is wet or covered in snow. It is also a quick and easy way to cook food while camping, especially if you have limited wood to burn.
>
> [image: top-down view]
>
> #### Benefits of a Swedish Fire Log
>
> While there are countless ways to make a campfire, the Swedish Fire Log offers some distinct advantages – especially for cooking.
>
> ***Efficient Use of Wood* –**  By carefully arranging the wood from a single log, the Swedish Fire Log produces a directional flame that burns from the inside out.
>
> ***Flat Surface for Cooking* –** Placing the end of the log face down gives you a flat surface on the top for cooking. Depending on the size of your log, this surface can easily accommodate a water kettle, dutch oven, or cast iron skillet. [Note: We used a camping dutch oven with legs to allow airflow to the fire beneath it]
>
> ***Quick, Usable Flame* –**  Because the flames of a traditional campfire are hard to control, it is usually best to wait until it burns down to embers before cooking. This can easily take over an hour. The Swedish Fire Log concentrates the burn of the fire, allowing you to cook over a focused flame within 20 minutes.
>
> ***Keeps Fire Off of the Ground* –** Even with dry wood, it can be difficult to make a traditional campfire when the ground is very wet or covered in snow. The Swedish Fire Log method keeps the fire up off the ground to start, preventing vaporized water moisture from putting it out.
>
> ***Self Feeding / Self Ventilating* –** Unlike most campfires that need occasional tending, the Swedish Fire Log is completely self-sufficient once properly lit. As embers burn at the top, they fall down into the log, burning it from the top down. Air is continually drawn in through the slits on the side.
>
> [image: tools needed]
>
> #### Swedish Fire Log Variations
>
> There are a couple of different methods of making a Swedish Fire Log depending on the tools you have available. Here are your options:
>
> ***Chainsaw a Whole Log***
>
> [image: chainsaw a whole log]
>
> 1. Find or cut a suitably sized log with flat, level ends on either side.
> 2. With the log standing on its end, use a chainsaw to cut slits into the wood. Depending on the width of the log, this can be done in either quarters or sixths. [Note: Most chainsaws have crosscut blades, so cutting along the grain might be difficult. Use the bucking spikes as a fulcrum to get better leverage].
> 3. Do not cut all the way through. Leave few inches at the bottom, so the log remains a single unit so it is easier to transport and will maintain its structure while burning.
>
> ***Axe a Whole Log***
>
> [image: axe a whole log]
>
> 1. Find or cut a suitably sized log with flat, level ends of either side.
> 2. With a splitting axe or maul, split the log into quarters or sixths. [Note: It's okay if your splits aren't perfectly symmetrical].
> 3. Reassemble the log and keep the pieces together by using a metal coat hanger or bailing wire.
>
> ***Assemble Pre-Split Wood***
>
> [image: assemble pre-split wood]
>
> 1. Find pre-split wood of roughly equal height with flat, level ends. Thankfully, most pre-split firewood is cut to uniform lengths.
> 2. Arrange the split wood on its end, so it forms the appearance of a log, bark side facing out.
> 3. Use a metal coat hanger or bailing wire to secure wood at its base.
>
> [image: cut edges with a hatchet]
>
> Rough up the interior edges of the wood with a hatchet. These rough edges will catch embers as they fall down inside the log and help it start faster. You don't have to do the entire log, just the leading edge that faces the middle.
>
> [image: Starting the fire]
>
> Now that you have your fire log ready, here's how you get it started.
>
> - Gather kindling (dry sticks, fatwood) & tinder (birch bark, dry grass, paper).
> - Insert kindling in the center of the log. Don't over stuff or put kindling towards the outside of the log, as this will restrict airflow. A nice small bunch in the middle is all you need.
> - Place tinder and a small amount of kindling on top of the log in the center. Light the tinder.
> - The embers from this small fire on top of the log should fall down inside and catch the other pieces of kindling. After a short period of time, the logs themselves will catch fire and the fire will continue.

All images and quoted text from [How to Make a Swedish Fire Log](https://www.freshoffthegrid.com/swedish-fire-log/).